# How should I store similar entities - in one table or several?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-design

I am creating a CV website, but in difference to most I am trying to make it with database. I mean that usually such websites are static and all of the information is hard coded in the HTML. Since I am back-end developer I like to make it so everything including buttons and welcome messages are taken from the database. I am trying to store projects that I have worked on. There are several types:

1. Github Repository - a project that is done purely on github.
2. Work related - a project I have done on work and there is no github repository of it, only link to view the final result
3. UpWork or other freelance website - as a freelancer I have projects to fix something on a website and those projects can be viewed only on my profile there and I would like to list them with link to UpWork or wherever there is information on what exactly I was hired to do.

Now my question is - should I have different Entities and therefore different tables for these types of projects or should I have all of the possible properties in one table. For example if it is Github there is `repository` field and if it is work related then there is `company` field. If it is freelance it has link to the website I was hired on. Also there are different sub-types - web applications, desktop applications, games and so on.

As you can guess the changes are small (1 or 2 properties). I could very easily leave empty some properties and have another property `projectType`, but is this the right way? Should I have different tables and entities for them?

To give some info - I can work with both MySQL and NoSQL and I havent decided yet on which one should my website be made on. I am currently thinking about NoSQL. This means I am asking on how to store the projects on MySQL and NoSQL (by NoSQL I mean MongoDB). If it helps the languages I am choosing from are PHP (MySQL) and JavaScript (NoSQL)

I know that usually questions without code are downvoted, but this is more of a logic based problem as I know how to do it, but I don't know the best practices for my situation. This being said here is a small code for you -

`console.log('Thank you in advance')`

Comment: I'm sure there are thousands of dynamic sites of this type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB lends itself very well to this exact situation.

You can create a collection where documents leave out certain fields if they are not needed for that type. The querying parameters of MongoDB allow you to check [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) on fields if you need to, and documents are stored efficiently, only taking up memory where a field is needed.

You can even setup a sparse index which is not required for every document. As long as your core document structure is the same, it is a good idea to keep them in one collection, and vary them based on their type.

Comment: It crossed my mind, but I was thought that leaving some parameters empty is a bad practice. Would it make a bad impression if I was using this practice? I mean that since it is CV website I would like to use the best practices and the cleanest code possible.

Comment: As I said, mongodb is built for this. It's very much standard practice, and makes a lot of sense in the context of mongodb.
In the SQL world though, it's completely different. You COULD certainly use an SQL database here too, but it would be more work, and wouldn't give the same flexibility.
Basically, it would be good practice for you to use mongodb (or nosql in general) here. Leaving out fields in some documents is part of mongodb's design.